# How to get the value of memory address in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I am trying to access the value of a memory access, but I keep getting the address, when I print the output.

```
char c[16];

 char copyArray(unsigned char* state, unsigned char* key)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        state[i] ^= key[i];
         // c[i] =  state[i];      // this gave me the address
        printf("%02x", state[i]);
    }
        printf("\n");

               memcpy (c, state,16);

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {


        printf("%02d\n",c[i] );
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

This function is executed 10 times in another function. What I am trying to achieve is to store the value of the last execution instead of the address

Comment: Looks like you are already doing it, what makes you think you are printing the address?

Comment: when i'm printing the c array elements, they are not the same as state array elements

Comment: `c` array is probably signed, but `state` is definitely unsigned. Perhaps you are printing negative numbers and mistaking them for addresses. In one case you are using `%02x` and in the other `%02d`, so the outputs will not be the same.

Comment: @WeatherVane; yes, that might be true. The output I get is: 035411862-106109-110899086124-55-508312794 while I expect something like : 0336763e966d92595a567cc9ce537f5e

Comment: OK, `03` decimal is `03` hex. `54` dec is `36` hex. `118` dec is `76` hex, and so on. Use the same data type, and use the same format specifier.

Comment: That is right, because `c` is signed, any value in `state` that is 128 (`80` hex) or bigger will be printed as a negative number. Also you are printing one as hex and the other as decimal, so either way the outputs are going to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!

It is solved now. I made the c array unsigned, and that solved the problem

```
unsigned char c[16];

char copyArray(unsigned char* state, unsigned char* key)
{

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    state[i] ^= key[i];

    printf("%02x", state[i]);
}

printf("\n");

memcpy (c, state,16);

for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    printf("%02x\n",c[i] );
}
printf("\n");

}
```